# Solaris SPARC 10 32bit mode

Tags: solaris

I'm looking for a definitive answer, does Solaris 10 running on a SPARC machine support booting into 32bit mode?

I've found one site that states Solaris 8 was the last version that supported booting in a 32bit mode for SPARC.

I've read multiple items that explain how to boot Solaris into 32bit mode, however they did not list the Solaris version. We've tried all the ways specified, but the system keeps booting into 64bit mode.

Comment: I'm voting to move this to unix.SE, as it's a much higher chance of getting a proper answer there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it does not.  Solaris 10 only provides a 64-bit kernel for SPARC CPU's.

This was documented in the Solaris 10 Release Notes under [Features Removed From the Solaris 10 Operating System: SPARC: 32-bit Sun4U Kernel](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/html/817-0552/eos-5.html#eos-16):

> The 32-bit SPARC kernel is no longer included in Solaris OS. Existing 32-bit applications are not affected.